# easy way to rename URL in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I just want to make a change to the URL without getting an undefined method error. I can try to do it manually but is there an easy way to do so?

For example, on my local server, if the URL is:
/users/username/XYZ

Is there an easy way to change "XYZ" to something else easily?

Comment: you can change the route

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "an easy way to do so." Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. The only way to modify your routes is by, well, modifying your routes in `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: I tried.. this is what I put into routes - resources :XYZ, :path => "ABC" and the links didn't change

Answer (score 0):

If XYZ is a part of a resourceful route you may modify it like this

```
resources :users, :path_names => { :new => 'make', :edit => 'change' }
```

OR

if you want to change the name of the resource only you may change it like this:

```
resources :person, :controller => 'users', :as => 'users'
```

this would change the urls to 'person' and maintaining all class and method names.

Here is the `rake routes` output:

```
    users GET    /person(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /person(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /person/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /person/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /person/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /person/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /person/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

You can find out more on how to customize resourceful routes here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be exactly what u are looking for :) ...

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised

Regards